# django + django_allauth + android application

Tags: android, django, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, django-allauth

The story up to here:

- we wrote a django application
- we have working authentication (OAuth2) against Google Accounts with the use of django-allauth

Now we would like to connect to the application with Android client and make it as simple as possible for user to signup/login.

I know how to get the user account on Android with the use of AccountManager and I understand how to get a token from Google (http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html). But I have some problems understanding how to perform sign-up or log-in into django with the said token. Can anybody shed some light on this or provide an example/tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this out, that was the answer from the django-allauth's author himself. And that's what I usually do to signup with Oauth access tokens.

[Connect facebook phonegap login with django allauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834514/connect-facebook-phonegap-login-with-django-allauth)

Comment: Thank you. I already seen that one, but I do not like the IAB approach as I would like to do all this stuff in the background - the first time the user accepts that he will share the credentials with me then I will not bug him with login stuff any more.