# Django website as a backend with Google+ Login

Tags: android, django, authentication, google-plus

This gonna be a kind of design question.

I'd like to create a website that uses Google+ as login service. I know I'll be able to do this using *python-social-auth*.

And I'd like to create an Android app, that uses this site as a backend.

I imagine this in the following way: on startup my Android app authenticates the user with Google, and get an *id*/*token*/*whatever* from Google. The POST this id to my site (to a specified login page) in a HTTP POST, and my site responses with a simple HTTP response containing his `sessionId` and `csrftoken` as a cookie.

After this I'll include this cookies in every call, that my app makes to my server.

Is it a possible way to do this? Is there any better way?

If it's the best way, how will my server be able to *authenticate* that user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This post helped me a lot to set up a similar structure: http://blog.wizer.fr/2013/11/angularjs-facebook-with-a-django-rest-api. You will have to change angularjs with android but requests are exactly the same and it works. Basically, the steps the post explains are:

- Obtain Google+ credentials with the client. You end with an access token.
- Send this access token to your backend. With python-social-auth, request the data for that user, if it doest not exist, create a new user with the data. It also creates an access token (using drf token authentication).
- Send back this token to the user. Now, the user can do requests to your api using this token. Another step could be added in case you want this tokens to expire.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834514/connect-facebook-phonegap-login-with-django-allauth) that could help you.

As it is mentioned in the answer, you can either do the login using the main application or login to google and then send the credentials as you want.

To handle the communication with your site i recommend using a REST api. There are several alternatives, with [django-REST-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and [tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html) leading the charts. I know django-REST-framework includes an oauth and oauth2 implementation, have not worked with tastypie